# how can I calculate statistic distributions (std and mean) of my dataset?

Tags: python, pytorch-dataloader

I have created a custom dataset and I am wondering how can I calculate statistic distributions (std and mean) of my dataset

I have created the following code but I am not sure if it's correct

```
python
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

# Assuming you have a dataset object named 'dataset'
batch_size = 64
data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

mean = 0.0
std = 0.0
num_samples = 0

for data in data_loader:
    images, labels = data
    
    # Calculate batch statistics
    batch_size = images.size(0)
    num_samples += batch_size
    mean += images.mean(0).sum(0)
    std += images.std(0).sum(0)

# Calculate overall statistics
mean /= num_samples
std /= num_samples

print("Mean:", mean)
print("Standard Deviation:", std)
```

Comment: Mean and std are only for fixed dimensionality (ideally, 1D) data, and aren't really applicable to images

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the mean, std of pixels values? That is a use case for normalizing image color. There is a solution, if that is what your asking.

Comment: @Jesse Sealand  yes, I'm looking for channel-wise (RGB) mean and std. Three values, one for Red, one for Blue, and one for Green

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:

Here is how you would iterate over a list of file images and get the average r,g,b,a values for each image.

```
rgba = []

for file in tqdm(files):
    
    img = Image.open(file)
    img_arr = np.asarray(img)
    avg_rgba = np.mean(img_arr, axis=(0, 1))
    rgba.append(avg_rgba.tolist())
```

Then putting this into a dataframe, which would look something like as follows...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rgba,columns=["r","g","b","a"])

# r g   b   a
# 0 99.669712   100.225186  100.389371  12.797314
# 1 137.264169  137.872926  133.018785  7.097168
# 2 91.039830   92.197714   94.923710   6.533704
# 3 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    9.202194
# 4 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    7.148724
```

You can simply take the mean of each column to get your values, like

```
df.mean()
```

Voila!